# python selenium 'geckodriver needs to be in your path' error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

so, i wanted to work with selenium with python but everytime i get an error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lario/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/home/lario/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/lario/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

i have tried to run this code

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/lario/Desktop/workstation/geckodriver
```

but it just keeps saying this. Is there a way to put this in all directories?
  And how do i fix the first error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: these answers still dont work, i cant copy and past my geckodriver

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are adding `geckodriver` to path and not the folder containing `geckodriver` to the path. Use below

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/lario/Desktop/workstation/
```

Comment: Thnx but i already fixed it, i needed to put geckodriver in /usr/bin/